# How to do something when EditText is activated

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm looking for an option to do something when EditText is touched, but I want it to be writeable, cause I found few solutions for it, but then the EditText turned to be unwriteable and I could only click it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
EditText ed == //to its reference
ed.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
ed.setOnTouchListener(/*add a listener */);
//also remember to add ed.requestFocus(); in your listener
```

i guess the above should work right?

Comment: It's working but on second click, on first click nothing happens.

Comment: hmm then remove the line `èd.setFocusableInTouchMode(true)` and try again, if not you need to extend Edittext class and override onTouchEvent. @LisSkis